# Error: Veins:: TraCiScenarioManagerLaunchd

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I tried to set up veins on Windows 10 like the official tutorial on http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/. All steps work fine but if I want to start the last simulation by omnetpp.ini I get this message:

```
Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunched)
RSUExampleScenario.manager(id=6) at Event #1,t=0: Connection to TraCI Server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 10054: Unknown error.
```

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is your sumo version 0.25? Did you specify correctly the sumo path as: `/c/Users/user/src/sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe` ? Can you run sumo from the terminal writing the `sumo-gui` or `sumo` command?

Answer (score 1):

SUMO is running correctly?

See the most common error and FAQ [here](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/).

With message (error) the SUMO display?

Comment: Yes, SUMO is running fine.

Comment: With message (error) the SUMO display?
Paste the full log here.
[TraCI](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI) handles the mobility SUMO <=> Veins.
"Connection to TraCI Server lost. Check your server's log"
Means the TraCI/SUMO got an error and some part of the scenario.

Comment: Do you mean the message after <pre> Listening port 9999 <code>?

Comment: Connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50057
Handling connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50057
Aborting on error: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50057

Comment: Are you using the scenario with came with Veins?
I don't have Windows for one test, but you can try run just the sumo and the scenario. `sumo-gui -c erlangen.sumo.cfg` or `sumo-gui -c erlangen.sumo.cfg`. You can use `sumo` for the terminal mode and `sumo-gui` for the GUI mode.
If running only the scenario works, we can look further for error in TraCI.
The SUMO print some another good info in the error message?
"Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly" isn't a common error.

Comment: You might have a different version of Python installed. Can you try on another machine (or, preferably, on Linux)?

Comment: And maybe run the simulation with the ./debug script (gdb) instead of ./run to get more information. For instance you can print the current stack at the time the error occurs.